# Avoid output disappearing in psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

I open `psql` and write:

```
mydb=> \dt
```

and this list of tables is shown:

```
                   List of relations
 Schema |            Name            | Type  |  Owner  
--------+----------------------------+-------+---------
 public | auth_group                 | table | foouser
 ...
```

The I have to press `Esc` to return to the prompt, and the output disappears like it was a `less` session.

I want to keep the output around so that I can use the information in it to write queries, but googling does not find an option to do that.

Comment: It looks like if the terminal is big enough, the output is printed instead of being opened in this sort of `less`. However, this only solves the problem for outputs which are fewer than 30 lines or so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming your pager is `less`, try `LESS=-FX; export LESS` in your shell environment.

From `man less`:

```
      -F or --quit-if-one-screen
              Causes less to automatically exit if the entire file can be dis‐
              played on the first screen.

      -X or --no-init
              Disables sending the termcap initialization and deinitialization
              strings to the terminal.  This is  sometimes  desirable  if  the
              deinitialization  string does something unnecessary, like clear‐
              ing the screen.
```

To have this only in psql, set it with a meta-command in `.psqlrc`:

```
\setenv LESS -FX
```

Answer (score 7):

You can [turn off the use of the pager](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS) through

```
\pset pager off
```